# \glspostdescription for longnewglossaryentry

Tags: glossaries, fill

In the following MWE I try to dotfill the space between the end of description and the page numbering by defining `\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill\kern1ex}`. It seams to work with `\newglossaryentry`s but not with `\longnewglossaryentry`s.

```
\documentclass{article}


% use glossaries and acronyms
\usepackage[indexonlyfirst]{glossaries}
% dots between glossary description and page number
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill\kern1ex}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{
    name={Foo},
    description={lorem ipsum dolor }
}

\longnewglossaryentry{bar}
{
    name={Bar}
}
{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. 


    Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellent
}



\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\glsaddallunused 
\printglossaries

The \gls{foo} is awesome. But \gls{bar} is better.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see in the rendering, the `\newglossaryentry` have his whole line doted when `\longnewglossaryentry` haven’t.

So how to get postdescription dotfilled for `\longnewglossaryentry`’s rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\longnewglossaryentry` disables the `\glspostdescription` hook. The [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package provides a starred version that doesn't disable the hook (added to version 1.12). With `glossaries-extra`, you can redefine the post-description hook for specific categories. This means that you can combine it with the `postpunc` package option.

Modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}    

% use glossaries and acronyms
\usepackage[postpunc=comma]{glossaries-extra}

% indexonlyfirst:
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{indexonlyfirst}{true}

% dots between glossary description and page number
\renewcommand*\glsxtrpostdescgeneral{\dotfill\kern1ex}
% or (requires v1.31)
%\glsdefpostdesc{general}{\dotfill\kern1ex}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{
    name={Foo},
    description={lorem ipsum dolor }
}

% requires glossaries-extra.sty v1.12+:
\longnewglossaryentry*{bar}
{
    name={Bar}
}
{% comment out space caused by end of line
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. 


    Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend
mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu
massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellent% comment out space caused by end of line
}   

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

First use:
The \gls{foo} is awesome. But \gls{bar} is better.

\newpage
Next use:
The \gls{foo} is awesome. But \gls{bar} is better.

\glsaddallunused % must always be at the end of the document
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary with dotted leaders followed by comma between description and page number]

The other difference between the starred and unstarred versions of `\longnewglossaryentry` is that the unstarred version also appends `\unskip` at the end of the description, which discards the trailing space cause by the uncommented line at the end of your long description. The starred version doesn't do this. Neither version trims leading space.

Tips:

- `\glsaddallunused` should always be placed at the end of the document. At the start of the document, none of the entries have been used, so you end up with every entry indexed at that point but the page number is ignored in the location list, which can lead to spurious commas following phantom locations.
- `\makeglossaries` is best placed before entries are defined. (It doesn't make a difference in this instance, but does make a difference if you include the `see` or `seealso` key in any of your entries.)